# Can't add things to Wallet under Family Sharing

Tags: wallet

My daughter is on my Family Sharing, and it correctly registers her as 14. However, the "+" button does not appear in the Wallet app on her phone. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you verified you're in a supported location and, if so, she's using a supported device and iOS version?

Comment: I'm not sure what "supported location" means, but we're in the US. She's on an iPhone 5s running iOS 12.